# How to assign static constexpr field value based on template type

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'd like to assign static constexpr field of a class based on template type.
I've found out below solution but I guess it is not best solution especially if there are other types to support. Maybe some kind of constexpr map?
(I can use STL and/or boost)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

template <typename T>
struct Example
{
    static constexpr std::string_view s{std::is_same_v<T, int> ? "int" 
         : (std::is_same_v<T, double> ? "double" : "other")};
};


int main()
{
    const Example<int> example;
    std::cout << example.s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems to me like the true problem is how to convert a type to string?

Comment: *"best solution..."* Opinion based, micro-optimization?

Comment: Use `if constexpr`?

Comment: @user12002570 this question is tagged c++14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a trait

```
template <typename T> 
struct st { };
```

and specialize it accordingly:

```
template <> struct st<int> { static constexpr std::string_view value{"int"}; }
// ... other types
```

then use it:

```
template <typename T>
struct Example
{
    static constexpr std::string_view s = st<T>::value;
};
```

Alternatively you could write a function that utilizes a series of `constexpr if` to return the right string for given type. Though, I wouldn't expect this to be cleaner or more readable.

Comment: I think this is fine. With constexpr (even if it is more moderen) you would get a long nested if which is by itself also not all that readable.

Comment: @PepjinKramer I only mentioned it for the sake of completeness. So far, in all examples I have encountered where the two were alternatives imho the traits variant was cleaner and more readable compared to the `constexpr if`. Though, I am rather old fashioned, stuck with c++11, for most of my work

Comment: Sure fair enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use constepxr function specialization instead of specializing a struct. That also allows you to detect unsupported types if you want to.

```
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

namespace details
{

template<typename type_t>
inline constexpr std::string_view as_string()
{
    // example of how to alert at compile time an "other" type is encountered
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<type_t,type_t>, "unsupported type");
    return "other";
}

// provide specializations for the types you want to support
template<> inline constexpr std::string_view as_string<int>(){ return "int"; }
template<> inline constexpr std::string_view as_string<double>(){ return "double"; }

}

template<typename type_t>
struct Example
{
    static constexpr std::string_view s{details::as_string<type_t>()};
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Example<int> example;
    static_assert(example.s == "int");

    //constexpr Example<char> example_fail; <== this will now not compile with error : static_assert failed: 'unsupported type' 
}
```

Comment: `static_assert(!std::is_same_v<type_t,type_t>)` is pedantically identical to `static_assert(false)`. ill-formed (before C++23? and after, ok if not instantiated). even if compiler doesn't catch your variant.

Comment: See [Defect_reports](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert#Defect_reports) accepted in C++23, applied to previous version.

Comment: @Jarod42 regrettably it is a workaround to the way msvc (2022) handles static_assert(false) it will prematurely trigger during compilition :(